# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: лексика

"Учился *НА (по)* дневной форме обучения в вузе".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А "на дневном отделении" не подходит?
Или это официальный документ?

Comment: Подходит. Но хочется узнать именно этот случай)

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, ПО.

Answer (score 0):

Хочется призвать всех, кому дорог русский язык:" Друзья, давайте всем миром начнём бороться с предельной бюрократизацией языка, с выхолащиванием из него всего живого! Язык делового документа - не обязательно мёртвый язык." Почему бы действительно просто не написать, как предлагает АлексейII:"учился в вузе на дневном отделении"? 
Наличие двух однокоренных слов - "учился" и "обучение" - в одном коротком предложении считаю перебором.